# Searching for temporal avd image

Tags: android

Im searching for the .img file of my running Android avd. It should be located under %profilename%\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator, but i can only see some logs there. Is it possible to change the location for this file at emulator startup?

Answer (score 0):

Image files are usually stored in `YOUR_SDK_HOME_DIR/sdk/system-images/{android-version-number}/system.img`.

This can differ from the operating system and if PlayStore services are enabled, for me (Linux) it's in the `~/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-29/google_apis_playstore/x86/system.img`